# How can i 'echo' html code in my page (PHP)?

Tags: php, html

I need to create a function that generates html code. This will output html to client for copy.

How can i do this?

For sample:

```
$htmlCode = "<div class='redRectangle'></div>";
```

If i `echo $htmlCode` this will show a `div`, but i need to show the code.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: echo htmlentities($htmlCode);

Comment: use `<pre> code </pre>`

Comment: @farmer1992 that won't work 100%

Comment: @Vallentin just post a different idea `<code> </code>` or `<pre> </pre>` and any counter example?

Comment: @farmer1992 This `<pre><i>Hello World!</i></pre>` and this `<code><i>Hello World!</i></code>` will still make the "Hello World!" text become italic and "hide the tags", the OP wanted to show the HTML as text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

```
echo htmlentities($htmlCode);
```

Comment: Or `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @JoaoPaulo why not just test it, would probably be 100 times faster than waiting for a response.